# Focal "Failed to enroll new fingerprint" on Gigabyte Aero 15 2020

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I decided to liberate my Aero 15 from Windows and I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 Focal on it. When I try to add my fingerprint through the settings application, it starts out working and reads once, then fails to read and says "Failed to enroll new fingerprint". If I press cancel and try again, it says enrollment is already in progress. The reader is from ElanTech with ID of `04f3:0c11`. Does anyone else experience this issue? Or on another device with the same reader?

Comment: Can someone please answer this? I'd really like to use this feature of my $2700 computer. Upgrading to 20.10 did not help.

Comment: This seems to be now part of 21.04. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en. I tried it on my Aero15 but couldn't do get any fingerprint swiped correctly :(